# failed to upload to android market

Tags: java, android, google-play, android-manifest

I am trying to upload an app to google play but keep getting this error:

> Upload failed
>
> You uploaded an APK or Android App Bundle which specifies an actions schema document in its manifest, but action schemas are not yet allowed. If you are part of a beta program, you need to have your developer account whitelisted.

Can somebody please explain what I am doing wrong? I have uploaded apps in the past, butn never come across this error before.

Here is my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="my package name">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<application
    android:name="my app name"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">


    <activity
        android:name="My main activity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity android:name="Genres" />
    <activity android:name="home" />
    <activity
        android:name="playerlayout"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true" />

   
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.OPTIONS_PROVIDER_CLASS_NAME"
        android:value="my package name.CastOptionsProvider" />

    <activity android:name="layouts" />
    <activity android:name="layouts" />
    <activity android:name="layouts" />
    <activity android:name="layouts" />
    <activity android:name="my layouts" />
    <activity android:name="my layouts" />
    <activity android:name="my layouts" />
    <activity android:name="my layouts" />
    <activity android:name="my layouts" />
    <activity android:name="my layouts" />
    <activity
        android:name="my layouts"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
        android:largeHeap="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="my layouts" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
        android:value="my value" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.actions"
        android:resource="@xml/app_prefs" />

    <activity
        android:name="my layouts"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"
        android:label="@string/action_settings" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: check this . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55048143/cant-upload-to-play-store/55049187

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error message suggests that the error comes from the use of:

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.actions"
    android:resource="@xml/app_prefs" />
```

Did you add this recently? It looks like the use of Android actions are still under a whitelist.

Comment: yeah its used in one of googles samples so i find it strange that we cant use it.. it leads to a pref xml with my app info inside. things such as build number and credits to a few packages used