# Can't upload to play store

Tags: android, google-play

Whenever I try to upload this app to the play store I get this error:"You uploaded an APK or Android App Bundle which specifies an actions schema document in its manifest, but action schemas are not yet allowed. If you are part of a beta program, you need to have your developer account whitelisted."

here is my manifest:

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="scanfeira.kcollector.com.br.kcollectorfeira">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:name="com.orm.SugarApp"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/kcollector"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:replace="android:icon">

        <meta-data
            android:name="DATABASE"
            android:value="kcollectorFeira.db" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="VERSION"
            android:value="2" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="QUERY_LOG"
            android:value="true" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="DOMAIN_PACKAGE_NAME"
            android:value="scanfeira.kcollector.com.br.kcollectorfeira.model" />

        <activity
            android:name=".TelaInicial"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".scan.CameraScan"
            android:screenOrientation="fullSensor"
            android:stateNotNeeded="true"
            android:theme="@style/zxing_CaptureTheme"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" />
        <provider
            android:name=".GenericFileProvider"
            android:authorities="scanfeira.kcollector.com.br.kcollectorfeira"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">

        </provider>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1):

Possible that one of the libs you use delares this: android:name="com.google.android.actions"
Look at this merged AndroidManifest.xml to confirm that theory:

/project/module/build/intermediates/manifests/full/debug/AndroidManifest.xml