# Receiving an error when uploading app to google play

Tags: android, upload, apk, android-manifest, google-developers-console

I keep getting the following error when uploading an app to google play:.. 
*You uploaded an APK or android App Bundle which specifies an actions schema document in its manifest, but action schemas are not yet allowed. If you are part of a beta program, you need to have your developer account whitelisted.*

I have applied to become whitelisted, but when I filled out the form my app did not meet the criteria for an specific 'type'  (it is not a financial program etc.)

Most of the articles I have read say this relates to meta data content which some say can be deleted...  my app however, will not work without the metadata content.

````
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths" /> 


and here is the resource file_paths

<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path
        name="ConfinedSpace_images"
        path="Android/data/com.mynamehere.confinedspacemanagement/files/Pictures" />
</paths> ```

Does anyone know of a workaround?
````

Comment: i think your problem is same to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53403806/failed-to-upload-to-android-market)

Comment: Thank you Mahmoud.  I had found that site while I was researching.  Their answer was to remove the meta data, however my app will not function without it  :(

Comment: As per the error message, only selected developers are allowed to use this meta-data. This is not a public feature yet. If your app depends on it, your best bet is to try reaching out to Play developer support to aek if you can join the beta-test and be whitelisted as well.

Comment: Thank you Pierre.  I found the application 'page' to become white-listed, but even that was a bit confusing. When they ask what type of program you are writing, they provide a list of choices such as food, financial etc.   My meta data is simply in place to take pictures and save files and that type wasn't listed.  Thank you for confirming.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is no getting around the google whitelist problem.  I also found that my manifest had two areas of meta-data in it.  The file system seems to be fine, but the following code seems to be where my problem is originating

```
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.actions"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
```

I have deleted the meta data above and things still seems to work.  I am curious though...  where did the code come from, and more importantly....   what does it do?  I openly admit I am still somewhat of a copy and paste programmer.

My problem now is that my camera will not work in my app????  any advice?

Update Dec 2/2019 -----   Camera now works fine.  My problem was that the xml file_path resource wasn't changed...  it was still trying to save to com.example.-----------